# Design pattern to implement plugins that depend on other plugins

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, plugins, dependencies

I'm writing a tool that takes some data manually input by the user every 10 minutes, and runs a set of calculations on each input. Plugin A provides one calculation, Plugin B provides another, and so on. Mostly these plugins are independent of one another, *i.e.* order doesn't matter, because each plugin's calculation returns an integer that gets summed with the other plugins' integers.

But suppose now, I do have a Plugin C that depends on, say, whether Plugin A's return was non-zero. Data-wise, let's say I know how to make Plugin A's states available to Plugin C. (If it were C++, I'd make Plugin A a `friend` of Plugin C, for example. However, I'm writing this in Javascript, so I may take a looser approach.) My question is more about the pattern for ordering / dependence. **How do I ensure that Plugin A's calculation runs before Plugin C's?**

Of course, the simplest approach is to simplly "install" the plugins in the order they need to run, *i.e.* insert the plugins in the right order into an array so the loop looping through said array doesn't need to think.

But this may become fragile as I add more and more plugins (upwards of 20, maybe 30, depending on the scenario). I'd like something more robust.

The best idea I have right now is:

1. On "installing" a plugin, I supply an array of plugins it depends on.
2. Each plugin will have a static member, say, `_complete`, that indicates whether it was run, and gets reset on every new iteration (user input).
3. As I loop through each plugin, I check each plugin's dependency's `_complete` states; and if one isn't complete, then I don't run the calculation yet; the loop will be a `while`-loop that comes back to retry this plugin after attempting all the others. I'll also have a maximum-retries guard to prevent infinite loops.

**How can this be improved?**

Comment: Use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Hm, RequireJS seems to be for managing file dependencies, not runtime dependencies... I'm not sure how to apply that to my situation?

Comment: If your modules are asynchronous, use Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gothdo suggested, Promises would work well on a problem like this. However, your code does not need to be async. There are no constraints in mixing and matching async and sync code when using promises. You will end up paying a performance overhead if your running loads of small synchronous functions, but with your use case of tens of functions the overhead is negligible.

Promises provide control flow abstraction for things that happen in the future: Run this, when that completes. Mostly used for async code. An argument might be made that this is hunting ducks with a minigun. I justify the choice with an argument about reinventing the wheel (or finding an obscure hexagonal wheel from the depths of GitHub), having a support for async ready, if the need arises and the fact that most JS programmers are already familiar with Promises and libraries are well supported. And the biggest one: Making the necessary wrapper around promises is extremely simple.

I made a quick sketch of what such a wrapper might look like. The code uses somewhat ugly deferred-pattern to enable adding tasks in any order. Feel free to add error handling, or otherwise modify to suit your needs.

```
function TaskRunner () {
    this.tasks = {};

    // name: String
    // taskFn: fn(dep_1_result, dep_1_result...) -> result or Promise(result), 
    // deps: Optional, array of names or a name.
    // Return: Promise over added task
    TaskRunner.prototype.add = function (name, taskFn, deps) {
        var self = this;
        deps = (deps === undefined ? [] : (deps instanceof Array ? deps : [deps]));
        name = name.toString();
        self.tasks[name] = self.tasks[name] || {};

        if(self.tasks[name].fn)
            throw "Task " + name + " exists."

        deps = deps.map(function (d) {
            // Create result handler for deps, if none exist
            self.tasks[d] = self.tasks[d] || {};
            self.tasks[d].result = self.tasks[d].result || defer();
            return self.tasks[d].result.promise;
        });

        // Create result handler for this task if none was created when
        // handling deps of formely created tasks
        self.tasks[name].result = self.tasks[name].result || defer();

        // Excecute when all deps are done
        self.tasks[name].fn = Promise.all(deps).spread(taskFn)
            .then(function(res, err) {
                // Trigger own result handler
                if(err) {
                    self.tasks[name].result.reject(err);
                    throw err;
                }
                else {
                    self.tasks[name].result.resolve(res);
                    return res;
                }
            });

        return self.tasks[name].fn;
    }
}
```

Example usage: https://jsfiddle.net/3uL9chnd/4/

Bluebird promise lib: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html

Edit, disclaimer: There's another point when considering overhead: reset efficiency. If you're running light calculations on a tight interval, creating a promise object for each task on each cycle makes this approach less than optimal.